# Setting dropdown width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How to set the dropdown width to the longest string length in the list of dropdown options using `<Select>`?
To implement in React JS

Tried with React JS but unable to get the solution.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: How do you calculate string width? Do you use fixed font size? Elaborate, provide example.

Comment: Assume that the API is returning the dropdown values const options =['apple','mango','grapes','watermelon'] here the 'watermelon' string length is greater than all other options , so the dropdown width should be set to the length of 'watermelon'

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have an array of all dropdown value like this,

```
const menuValue = [
'Value',
'Value2222222222222222',
'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry',
];
```

let say you want to set the width to the 3rd element of the menuValue array (longest element of that array)

for that you need to set your width like,

```
const length =
menuValue.reduce((text, newText) =>
  newText.length > text.length ? newText : text
).length * 10;
```

and pass it to the width like `` {width=`${length}px`} ``

please [prefer this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-57abkx?file=demo.js) for better understanding.

I hope it resolves your problem.